# importing android gradle project in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle

i am developing an android application in eclipse.now i am going to use a functionality that requires https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view this library.

this library is based on gradle. this library also requires another library that also built by gradle (https://github.com/suckgamony/RapidDecoder) how can i integrate these libraries with my application in eclispe .

Comment: CLI . /gradlew would handle your builds ok  and u could use eclipse editor. Tho android  studio n gradle seem to be calling you

Comment: @RobertRowntree i could not understand your comment. can u elaborate it plz..

Comment: Can build from command line using gradlew. Can edit in eclipsebut libs wont be reflected in cp

Comment: @RobertRowntree can i get the required dependencies as jar files from building it from commandline using gradleew

Comment: Gradle / maven get all dependencies for you. They will be on cp for builds under gradlew automatically

Comment: The library doesn't need the RapidDecoder dependencies unless you are having problems with the default decoder, so you only need to add `com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.1.2` as a dependency for a default setup.

Comment: @DaveMorrissey yeah, it worked without the rapid decoder library .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get .aar files for some dependencies and extract those .aar

http://www.nodeclipse.org/projects/gradle/android/aar-for-Eclipse